# How do you call a function only once until victory conditions are met?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Higher Lower</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Higher - Lower</h1>

    <!--maxNum Function-->
    <!-- <p>Please enter a maximum number:</p>
    <input type="text" id="maxNum" /><br /><br /> -->
    <button onclick="userInput()">Input Maximum Number</button>

    <p id="ranNum"></p>

    <p id="validation"></p>

    <!--higherLower Function-->
    <p>Your Guess:</p>
    <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="choice" /><br /><br />
    <button onclick="higherLower()">Guess</button>

    <p id="result"></p>

    <p id="values"></p>
  </body>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
let userMax;
function userInput() {
    userMax = prompt("Please enter a maximum number:");
   
    while (userMax < 1 || isNaN(userMax)) {
        alert("Maximum number cannot be negative, zero, or non-numbers");
        userMax = userInput();
    }

    return userMax;
}

function isFloat(userMax) {
    return Number(userMax) === n && n % 1 !== 0;
}

function higherLower(choice) {
    // Declares random number variable
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * userMax) + 1;
    window.alert(randomNumber);
    
    // Declares user guess variable
    var guess=document.getElementById('choice').value;
    
    // Declares random number variable
    if(randomNumber==guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You got it!";
    }
    else if(randomNumber>=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    }
    else if(randomNumber<=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
    }
}
```

I am creating a number guessing game based on the user inputting the maximum number. I was wondering how I could generate the random number only once until the user guesses correctly?
I messed around with creating another function and nesting functions however I could not get anything solid to work.
Currently, the button calls the main game function each time it is clicked and I do not want to add other buttons/inputs to solve this issue.

Comment: Declare `randomNumber` outside the function and in the window scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * userMax) + 1;` outside of your function, and it should not be replaced when you call `higherLower()`.

If the user guesses correctly, then set `randomNumber` to another `Math.floor(Math.random() * userMax) + 1`

So, your code should look like this:

```
let userMax;
let randomNumber;
function userInput() {
    userMax = prompt("Please enter a maximum number:");
   
    while (userMax < 1 || isNaN(userMax)) {
        alert("Maximum number cannot be negative, zero, or non-numbers");
        userMax = userInput();
    }
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Number(userMax)) + 1;
    return userMax;
}

function isFloat(userMax) {
    return Number(userMax) === n && n % 1 !== 0;
}

function higherLower(choice) {
    // Declares random number variable
    window.alert(randomNumber);
    
    // Declares user guess variable
    var guess=document.getElementById('choice').value;

    
    // Declares random number variable
    if(randomNumber==guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You got it!";
        randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random() * Number(userMax)) + 1;
    }
    else if(randomNumber>=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    }
    else if(randomNumber<=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
    }
}
```

Comment: It just gives me a "NaN" alert error. I have tried it before but I also tried it again by just copying and pasting the code changes provided.

Comment: Ah, this is because your userMax variable is not a number, so Math.floor() isn't functioning correctly. I will adjust the code accordingly...ahh there's some issues here, let me revise and get back to you in a second.

Comment: Update: Check out the above script, this should work. The problem is that your randomNumber wasn't generated when you inputted userMax, so it just never changed. Now, when you call userInput(), it will generate the randomNumber for you to compare to. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for working through it! It works perfectly now and I understand where I was getting confused. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are generating a random number in every call to `higherLower` function
so you have to declare to variable outside and set up a random number to it out side this function

```js
let userMax;
let randomNumber;
function start() {
    userMax = prompt("Please enter a maximum number:");
    if (userMax < 1 || isNaN(userMax)) {
        alert("Maximum number cannot be negative, zero, or non-numbers");
        userMax = start();
    }

    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Number(userMax)) + 1;
}



function higherLower() {
    // Declares random number variable
    window.alert(randomNumber);
    
    // Declares user guess variable
    var guess=document.getElementById('choice').value;
    
    // Declares random number variable
    if(randomNumber==guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You got it!";
    }
    else if(randomNumber>=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    }
    else if(randomNumber<=guess) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
    }
}
```

And you do not have to use while in `while (userMax < 1 || isNaN(userMax))`
you just can put a simple if statement,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Higher Lower</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Higher - Lower</h1>

    <!--maxNum Function-->
    <!-- <p>Please enter a maximum number:</p>
    <input type="text" id="maxNum" /><br /><br /> -->
    <button onclick="start()">Input Maximum Number</button>

    <p id="ranNum"></p>

    <p id="validation"></p>

    <!--higherLower Function-->
    <p>Your Guess:</p>
    <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="choice" /><br /><br />
    <button onclick="higherLower()">Guess</button>

    <p id="result"></p>

    <p id="values"></p>
  </body>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

And I changed the name of `userInput` function to `start`